# Search on custom solr index

Tags: content-search, solr

I am trying to search on a solr core which contains static data without any Sitecore details.

```
<doc>
<str name="_property_text">1</str>
<str name="_itemnumber_string">1250000</str>
<str name="_propertykey_string">Black</str>
<doc>
```

When I try to make a search using the content search manager it will always return an empty result.

```
var index= ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("index_name");
 using (var ctx = comboIndex.CreateSearchContext()){
     var queryable = ctx.GetQueryable<CustomSearchModel>();
 }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the Sitecore Search API on a non-Sitecore index? Just use Solr.net.

Answer (score 1):

The field you're missing is going to be `_indexname`. It will need to be set to the name of the index you are searching, in your case `index_name`. If you look at the `Search.log` in the data folder, you will see exactly what query string Sitecore is generating. At the end, you should see that it is generating `fq=_indexname:index_name`. You can test this by adding the `_indexname` field to all of your documents and checking if they then get returned.

I believe that this is the only field that Sitecore requires, but there may be others.